# Is there a way to use the GregorianCalendar on the JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gregorian-calendar, java.util.calendar

Is there a way to have a column in the TableView show a proper date instead of:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?areFieldsSet=false...
```

I want to know because it's irritating having it displayed like that on the Date column I have and having to switch between Date and GregorianCalendar get's messy and annoying.

Comment: Use a cell factory....

Comment: @James_D I've seen that before, however, whenever I insert it, IntelliJ keeps doing this: new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, Date>, ObservableValue<Date>>() and changing Date to Calendar won't let it compile.

Comment: That's a cell **value** factory, not a cell factory.

Comment: [This popular tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/) summarizes the difference between cell factories and cell value factories nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommend using the [`java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), instead of legacy classes such as `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`, etc.

In any case, you can change how data in cells in a given column are displayed by using a cell factory on the column. In the case where your cell value factory is generating `Calendar` instances, you presumably have

```
TableColumn<MyTableType, Calendar> dateColumn ;
// ...
dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(...);
```

You can additionally do

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
dateColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<MyTableType, Calendar>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Calendar date, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(date, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
        }
    }
});
```

If you use the aforementioned `java.time` API, you represent a date with [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to do the formatting:

```
TableColumn<MyTableType, LocalDate> dateColumn ;
// ...
dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(...);
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
dateColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<MyTableType, LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(date, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(dateFormat.format(date));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This type of explanation is what I was expecting since I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Using `java.time` is certainly recommended, thank you. In the last snippet you can just use `date.toString()` since this produces the same ISO format as `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.